# Ordenar paquetes y clases en Java

Tags: java, netbeans

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola, quisiera cambiar el orden de las clases y de los paquedes, por ejemplo quiero que el paquete ejercicioes este abajo de operadores y lo mismo con las clases dentro del paquete operadores, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola JM499 ¿te refieres a lo que muestra NetBeans en su arbol de archivos?

Comment: @AlvaroC. asi es amigo, disculpa si es una pregunta muy basica, es que recien empiezo a familiarizarme con tdo esto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El orden predeterminado que usa Netbeans y la mayoría de las [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) para mostrar sus archivos o paquetes es de acuerdo a el abecedario y teniendo prioridad si los nombres son escritos con mayúsculas, por esa razón el orden de tus clases y paquetes se muestra en ese orden.

```
JavaApp/
├── amnesia/
│   ├── a.java
│   ├── b.java
│   └── main.java
├── bell/
│   ├── cal.java
│   └── puisor.java
└── resources/
    ├── totita.txt
    ├── ust.java
    └── x.java
```

Esto esta definido así principalmente por usabilidad en la IDE.

Si deseas cambiar el orden necesitarías renombrar (refactorizar el nombre).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]